# Delphi Thread Timeout giving leaks everywere

Tags: multithreading, delphi, memory-leaks, try-finally

So, I have implemented threading using THandle, like that:

```
procedure Calc_Prin;
type
  TTeste = record
    ptrClass: TSpAu;
    ptrTEMPO: ^integer;
  end;

var
  TEMPO: integer;
  RESULTADO: THandle;
  thrID: DWord;
  teste: TTeste;

  function THREAD_C(PTR: pointer): longint; stdcall;
  begin
    try
      CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
      TPtrTeste(PTR).ptrClass.Calc;
      TPtrTeste(PTR).ptrTEMPO^ := 1;
    finally
      ExitThread(1);
      CoUninitialize;
      result := 0;
    end;
  end;

begin
  RESULTADO := CreateThread(nil, 0, @THREAD_C, @teste, 0, thrID);
  WaitForSingleObject(RESULTADO, TEMPO_PERMITIDO); 

  SuspendThread(RESULTADO);
  CloseHandle(RESULTADO);
end;
```

When the thread goes OK(the timeout is not reached and the process isn't ended prematurely) there isn't any leak, but if the thread has some problem and reach the timeout, it gives me a lot of leaks, because, I guess, it just goes away from the function, ignoring all the try..finally where I free everything.

Is there any way to finalize the thread, and kill the leaks that it lets?

Comment: Your code is also wrong to use a local function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
type
  TSpAu = class
  public
    Cancelled: Boolean;
    procedure Calc;
  end;

  TPtrTeste = ^TTeste;
   TTeste = record
    ptrClass: TSpAu;
    ptrTEMPO: ^integer;
  end;

procedure TSpAu.Calc;
begin
  ...
  if Cancelled then Abort;
  ...
  if Cancelled then Abort;
  ...
end;


function THREAD_CALCULO(PTR: pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
  try
    with TPtrTeste(PTR)^ do
    begin
      try
        ptrClass.Calc;
        ptrTEMPO^ := 1;
      except
        ptrTEMPO^ := 0;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
  Result := 0;
end;

procedure Calc_Prin;
var
  TEMPO: integer;
  RESULTADO: THandle;
  thrID: DWord;
  teste: TTeste;
  ret: DWORD;
begin
  TEMPO := 0;

  teste.ptrClass := ...; // <-- whatever your TSpAu object is
  teste.ptrTEMPO := @TEMPO;

  RESULTADO := CreateThread(nil, 0, @THREAD_CALCULO, @teste, 0, thrID);
  if RESULTADO = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    ret := WaitForSingleObject(RESULTADO, TEMPO_PERMITIDO);
    if ret = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
    begin
      teste.ptrClass.Cancelled := True;
      ret := WaitForSingleObject(RESULTADO, INFINITE);
    end;
    if ret = WAIT_FAILED then RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    CloseHandle(RESULTADO);
  end;

  // use TEMPO as needed...
end;
```

Comment: but ptrTEMPO is integer, how can I assign a TSpAu to that?

Comment: @Romulo: No, `ptrTEMPO` is a **pointer to Integer** (`^Integer`), not an integer. Remy's code shows you exactly how to assign a `TSpAu` to it. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite Yep, but delphi can't compile that way, it tells me "E2010 Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'". And the code is like: 

  with TPtrTeste(PTR)^ do
    ptrTEMPO^ := ptrClass.Calc;

Answer (score 2):

You are calling ExitThread() what kills the thread immediately what means that the CoUninitialize() call isn't executed anymore. You don't need to call ExitThread yourself. It it sufficient to exit the thread function normally.

```
try
  // ...
finally
  CoUnintialize;
  Result := 1; // the value that you specified in the ExitThread() call
end;
```

Calling SuspendThread() may pause the thread but it will not execute the "finally" block, nor will it leave the Calc() function nor will it terminate the thread. You need to add a "has-terminated" check into your Calc() function, so that the thread can terminate gracefully.

EDIT:
Here is a pseudo code that allows your thread to terminate gracefully by changing the Calc() method to know about a potential timeout.

```
type
  ECalcTimedOut = class(Exception);

  TSpAu = class(...)
  protected
    FCalcTimedOut: Boolean;
    procedure CheckCalcTimedOut;
  end;

  PTeste = ^TTeste;
  TTeste = record
    ptrClass: TSpAu;
    ptrTEMPO: ^integer;
  end;

function THREAD_CALCULO(PTR: pointer): longint; stdcall;
begin
  CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
  try
    try
      PTeste(PTR).ptrClass.Calc;
      PTeste(PTR).ptrTEMPO^ := 1;
      Result := 1;
    except
      on ECalcTimedOut do
        Result := 0;
    end;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;

procedure Calc_Prin;
var
  TEMPO: integer;
  RESULTADO: THandle;
  thrID: DWord;
  teste: TTeste;
begin
  // ...
  teste.ptrClass.FCalcTimedOut := False;

  RESULTADO := CreateThread(nil, 0, @THREAD_CALCULO, @teste, 0, thrID);
  if WaitForSingleObject(RESULTADO, TEMPO_PERMITIDO) = WAIT_TIMEOUT then
  begin
    // Signal the Calc() method that it timed out
    teste.ptrClass.FCalcTimedOut := True;
    // Wait for the thread to terminate gracefully
    WaitForSingleObject(RESULTADO, INFINITE);
  end;
  CloseHandle(RESULTADO);
end;

procedure TSpAu.CheckCalcTimedOut;
begin
  if FCalcTimedOut then
    raise ECalcTimedOut.Create('Calc Timed out');
end;

procedure TSpAu.Calc;
begin
  CheckCalcTimeout;
  // do something
  while condition do
  begin
    CheckCalcTimeout;
    DoSomethingElse;
    CheckCalcTimeout;
    // do something
  end;
end;

procedure TSpAu.DoSomethingElse;
begin
  for I := 0 to 1000000 do
  begin
    CheckCalcTimeout;
    // do something
  end;
end;
```

Comment: And how can I add this "has-terminated" check? Because the problem inside the Calc() could be at any point..

Comment: A very simple way would be to use something like this: "if Canceled then raise ECalcCanceled.Create('Canceled');" and then you catch that exception in your thread function.

Comment: But if the thread timeout is reached, I can't notice it inside the Calc(). And if I could, how can I terminate the thread?

Comment: After "WaitForSingleObject" you can set a (global) variable named "Canceled" to True. And your Calc() method continually evaluates this (global) variable and if it becomes true it raises the ECalcCanceled exception (or if you want ECalcTimeout or how you'll name your exception class). This exception then has to bubble up to your thread function where is is catched (`except on ECalcCanceled do...`)

Comment: Ok, I catch the exception and then? what do I do to kill the thread?

Comment: The `try/except` that Andreas is talking about would be inside of `THREAD_CALCULO()`.  To kill the thread, set a flag that `Calc()` can check for, and if detected than raise the exception, which would be caught in `THREAD_CALCULO()`, and let it exit normally.

Comment: So, I tried like the code above, but doesn't work. the thread timeout is ignored and the process keep going on. I need to stop the process and clean all the leaks..